# How do I repeat an CSS3 animation but change it every time

Tags: css, animation, iteration, repeat

I'm trying to create a CSS3 animation with several TDs that repeat with a slight change in the animation-delay function. I want several stripes that appear one after the other with increasingly long delays.

Is there a shorthand way of repeating the existing code with each iteration of the TD without having to create a new CSS class for each line?

```
/* Code */
<style>
td[class="animation"]{
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        animation-name: example;
        animation-duration: 8s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-direction: alternate;
        }
        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        @-webkit-keyframes example {
            0% {background-color: #9A1321;}
            40% {background-color: white;}
            60% {background-color: white;}
            100% {background-color: #232F80;}
        }

        /* Standard syntax */
        @keyframes example {
            0% {background-color: #9A1321;}
            40% {background-color: white;}
            60% {background-color: white;}
            100% {background-color: #232F80;}
</style>

<body>
<table><tr><td class="animation" /></tr></table>
</body>
```

Thanks a lot for all your help!

Best,

James

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be a combination of your CSS class + some JavaScript code.

Just mantain your TD's without your class, and then with setTimeout (JavaScript), you can call a function that changes the class from your TD's

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, I'm coding animation for HTML email (a few specific clients will handle CSS3) so I'm limited to CSS. Any recommendations using only CSS?

Comment: All I can say then is that you research for the property "transition", adding some "ease"